# Eclipse keep running the class but print nothing

Tags: java

I'm trying to find all propotional resolutions for 1080P 21:9 (2560*1080).

For example:

> 3840   1620
>      ____ = ____
>      2560   1080
>
> Cross multiply: 3840 * 1080 = 2560 * 1620
>
> Solving 0 = 0

It means that 3840*1620 is proportional to 2560*1080.

To find all I wrote:

```
public void vai(){
    double B1 = 2560;
    double B2 = 1080;
    double T1 = 2561;
    double T2 = 1081;
    double calD = 0;
    double calE = 0;
    double d = 0;

    for (int i = 2561; i < 3500; i++){
        for (int k=1081; k < 2200; k++) {
            calD = B1*T2;
            calE = B2*T1;
            d = calD - calE;                
            if (d == 0.00){                 
                System.out.println(T1+ " X "+ T2 + " Result: " + d);
                T2 = T2+1;                  
            }

            else {                  
                T2 = T2+1;
            }

        }
        T1 = T1+1;
    }
 }
```

But Eclipse keep running and print nothing. BluJ too.
There is no change to CPU or Memory usage.

What is going on???

Comment: You need to step through the code in your debugger to see what it is _actually_ doing, which is not what you are expecting.  At the very least, add a `println` statement before the `if (d == 0)` and display the values of `T1`, `T2`, `calD`, `calE`, and `d`.  Hint: you are not incrementing `T1` and `T2` correctly.  Also, this is a rather poor way to solve the problem using brute force.

Comment: Why did you change your code in an edit without adding a comment to state what you did and why?? That's highly counterproductive.

Comment: Your approach does not really make sense; divide by common factors and you'll see that `2560 / 1080 = 64 / 27`. So the resolutions are `width = 64 * n; height = 27 * n` for `n=1,2,3,...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        double B1 = 2560;
        double B2 = 1080;
        double T1 = 2561;
        double T2 = 1081;
        double calD = 0;
        double calE = 0;
        double d = 0;
        while (T1 < 4000){
            T2 = 1081;
            while (T2 < 2200) {
                calD = B1*T2;
                calE = B2*T1;
                d = calD - calE;
                if (d == 0){                    
                    System.out.println(T1+ " X "+ T2 + " Result: " + d);
                    T2 = T2+1;                  
                }
                else {                  
                    T2 = T2+1;
                }
            }
            T1 += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Your code goes into an infinite loop because when it fails out of the nested while loop, it doesn't have any further directions and is stuck in the outer while loop. Let me know if there are any issues with it.

Comment: It worked perfecly. I see now. T2 value needed to be reset.